# Trying to prevent the movement of nested containers JqueryUI sortable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to configure the jQuery sortable with nested DIVs. I want to allow only items with the class moveFile, to be moved all other DIVs should be prevented from moving. In my example MoveDocument can be moved as expected. I want to prevent items with the numbers from being dragged and dropped and preventing the error message

> Error: {
> "message": "HierarchyRequestError: Node.insertBefore: The new child is an ancestor of the parent",
> "filename": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js",
> "lineno": 2,
> "colno": 0
> }
> .

To recreate the issue, click to the left of a number then drag the item down. When clicking and dragging item 2 or greater, the error occurs.

```js
            $(document).ready(function () { 
                $(".moveFldr").sortable({
                    connectWith: "div.moveFldr :not(.fldrIcon) :not(span)",
                    placeholder: "placeHolder",
                    cancel: ".fldrIcon, .voidDoc",
                });

                $(".fldrIcon").sortable("disable");
            });
```

```css
           .fldrIcon:before {
                cursor: pointer;
                content: counter(folders);
            }

            .voidDoc {
                text-decoration: line-through;
                text-decoration-color: red;
            }

            #voidDoc { 
                 background-color:#FFF;
                 border-radius:5px;
                 color:#000;
                 display:none; 
                 padding:5px;
                 min-width:400px;
                 min-height: 130px;
            }

            .voidedDoc, .newDoc, .oldDoc {
                text-decoration: none !important;
            }

            .placeHolder {
                border-style: dashed;
                border-color: #000;
                height: 15px;
            }

            .grnDot, .redDot, .ylwDot {
                height: 10px;
                width: 20px;
                border-color: #000;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                font-size: 10px;
                display:inline-block;
                text-align: center;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }

            .subFixField {
                font-weight: 700;
            }

            .fixField {
                text-align:center;
            }

            .grnDot {
                background-color: #5efc03;
                color: #000;
            }

            .redDot {
                background-color: #FF0000;
                color: #FFF;
            }

            .ylwDot {
                background-color: #ffff00;
                color: #000;
            }

            .fldrIcon {
                counter-increment: folders;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
       <div style="text-align:center;">
            <div class="inlineBlock moveFldr" style="text-align:left;">
                <div id="C1" class="moveFldr lnkItems" data-cid="1" style="padding-left:30px;">
                    <div id="F1" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Procedures for Suppliers</div>
                    <div id="C2" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="2" style="padding-left:30px;">
                        <div id="F2" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Performance of Activates</div>
                        <div id="L101" class="upDoc moveFile  fileIcon2 hideFile" style="margin-left: 15px;">MoveDocument</div>
                        <div id="C3" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="3" style="padding-left:30px;">
                            <div id="F3" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Verification Documents</div>
                            <div id="C4" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="4" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                <div id="F4" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Performance Evaluation</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="C5" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="5" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                <div id="F5" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Verification Reports</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="C6" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="6" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                <div id="F6" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Testing Water</div>
                                <div id="C19" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="19" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                    <div id="F19" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. 2022-2023</div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="C20" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="20" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                    <div id="F20" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. 2023-2024</div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="C21" class="moveFldr lnkItems ">
                                    <div id="F21" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr" style="padding-left:30px;">. 2024-2025</div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="C22" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="22" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                    <div id="F22" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. 2025-2026</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="C7" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="7" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                <div id="F7" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr" data-cid="7">. Supplier’s Certification</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="C8" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="8" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                <div id="F8" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Training Program</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="C10" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="10" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                <div id="F10" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Drug Testing</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="C11" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="11" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                <div id="F11" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Annual 3rd Party Audit</div>
                                <div id="C12" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="12" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                    <div id="F12" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr" data-cid="12">. Corrective Action Reports</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="C17" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="17" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                <div id="F17" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Other Documents</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="C9" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="9" style="padding-left:30px;">
                                <div id="F9" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Analysis Review</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your initialization.

Specifically, this is causing problems:

```
  $(".moveFldr").sortable({
    connectWith: "div.moveFldr :not(.fldrIcon) :not(span)",
    placeholder: "placeHolder",
    cancel: ".fldrIcon, .voidDoc",
  });

  $(".fldrIcon").sortable("disable");
```

Since your `.moveFldr` class exists in both what you want to move (`.moveFile`) and what you don't want to move (the `div`s with counters), you're running into unwanted behaviour.

You can simplify your initialization like so:

```
  $("#C2").sortable({
    cancel: ".moveFldr"
  });
```

`sortable` is attached / initialized on `#C2`, since, according to the [example in the documentation](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items), that where it's supposed to be (the parent holding the elements you want to sort).

Putting it all together:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
/*
  $(".moveFldr").sortable({
    connectWith: "div.moveFldr :not(.fldrIcon) :not(span)",
    placeholder: "placeHolder",
    cancel: ".fldrIcon, .voidDoc",
  });

  $(".fldrIcon").sortable("disable");
*/ 
    $("#C2").sortable({
        cancel: ".moveFldr"
  });
});
```

```css
.fldrIcon:before {
  cursor: pointer;
  content: counter(folders);
}

.voidDoc {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}

#voidDoc { 
  background-color:#FFF;
  border-radius:5px;
  color:#000;
  display:none; 
  padding:5px;
  min-width:400px;
  min-height: 130px;
}

.voidedDoc, .newDoc, .oldDoc {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.placeHolder {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: #000;
  height: 15px;
}

.grnDot, .redDot, .ylwDot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  border-color: #000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.subFixField {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fixField {
  text-align:center;
}

.grnDot {
  background-color: #5efc03;
  color: #000;
}

.redDot {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.ylwDot {
  background-color: #ffff00;
  color: #000;
}

.fldrIcon {
  counter-increment: folders;
}

/****** added *****/
.moveFile {
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div class="inlineBlock moveFldrrr" style="text-align:left;">
    <div id="C1" class="moveFldrrr lnkItems" data-cid="1" style="padding-left:30px;">
      <div id="F1" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldrrr">. Procedures for Suppliers</div>
      <div id="C2" class="moveFldrrr lnkItems " data-cid="2" style="padding-left:30px;">
        <div id="F2" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Performance of Activates</div>
        <div id="L101" class="upDoc moveFile  fileIcon2 hideFile" style="margin-left: 15px;">MoveDocument</div>
        <div id="L202" class="upDoc moveFile  fileIcon2 hideFile" style="margin-left: 15px;">I'm another thing you can move!</div>
        <div id="C3" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="3" style="padding-left:30px;">
          <div id="F3" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Verification Documents</div>
          <div id="C4" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="4" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div id="F4" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Performance Evaluation</div>
          </div>
          <div id="C5" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="5" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div id="F5" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Verification Reports</div>
          </div>
          <div id="C6" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="6" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div id="F6" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Testing Water</div>
            <div id="C19" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="19" style="padding-left:30px;">
              <div id="F19" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. 2022-2023</div>
            </div>
            <div id="C20" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="20" style="padding-left:30px;">
              <div id="F20" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. 2023-2024</div>
            </div>
            <div id="C21" class="moveFldr lnkItems ">
              <div id="F21" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr" style="padding-left:30px;">. 2024-2025</div>
            </div>
            <div id="C22" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="22" style="padding-left:30px;">
              <div id="F22" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. 2025-2026</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="C7" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="7" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div id="F7" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr" data-cid="7">. Supplier’s Certification</div>
          </div>
          <div id="C8" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="8" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div id="F8" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Training Program</div>
          </div>
          <div id="C10" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="10" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div id="F10" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Drug Testing</div>
          </div>
          <div id="C11" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="11" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div id="F11" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Annual 3rd Party Audit</div>
            <div id="C12" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="12" style="padding-left:30px;">
              <div id="F12" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr" data-cid="12">. Corrective Action Reports</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="C17" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="17" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div id="F17" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Other Documents</div>
          </div>
          <div id="C9" class="moveFldr lnkItems " data-cid="9" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <div id="F9" class="fldrIcon contextMenu moveFldr">. Analysis Review</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="L303" class="upDoc moveFile  fileIcon2 hideFile" style="margin-left: 15px;">I'm the last one, move me!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You'll notice that I've added two more moveable `div`s, and changed the CSS. Two extra `div`s were added so we'd have more elements to move around, and the CSS was changed to make the moveable `div`s stand out.

One more important change was to the `.moveFldr` ancestor elements (`#F2`,`#C2`,`#F1`,`#C1`, and the `.inlineBlock` parent of the `#C1` element), to eliminate their influence on the sortablility (since we're canceling sortability on `.moveFldr`, and our `.moveFile` was inside an element with that class).